# Checking if string contains all elements from vector? (R, dataframes, dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe, and in it, a column called names stores strings

```
name
'Ana, Mari'
'John, Doe'
'Stuart, Matthews'
```

I have a vector that stores a name in an unknown order. For instance,

```
v <- c('Ana', 'Mari')
v <- c('Mari', 'Ana')
```

I want to filter ALL the cells that contain ALL elements in the vector. Does anyone know a function that can do this?

I have this so far, but it's checking if the cells contain ANY of the elements in the cell (don't mind the cells containing extra elements that aren't matched to the vector, but all the elements in the vector should be contained in the cell).

`df <- df %>% filter(grepl(vector, col_name))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(stringr)

df = data_frame(name = c('Ana, Mari','John, Doe', 'Stuart, Matthews'))
v <- c('Mari', 'Ana')
```

Base R:

```
df[sapply(strsplit(df$name, split=", "), function(str) all(v %in% str)), ]
```

> ```
>        name
> 1 Ana, Mari
> ```

`tidyverse`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(all(v %in% str_split(name, ", ", simplify=TRUE)))
```

> ```
>        name
> 1 Ana, Mari
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
df %>% filter(rowSums(mapply(grepl, x=list(name), pattern=v))==length(v))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_detect` with `filter`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
     filter(str_detect(df$name, paste(v, collapse="|")))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#       name
#      <chr>
#1 Ana, Mari
```

Comment: This  returns true if it matches any of the members of v - e.g. it would match "Ana, Smith" as well as "Ana, Mari".  OP was trying to only return items that contained both "Ana" AND "Mari".